# Get current dynamic URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Been trying to run jQuery functions based on a dynamic url but having some issues.

Say my HTML file is called `myPage.html`

This is the code I am using to check the URL

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var splitPath = pathname.split("?");
var input = splitPath[splitPath.length-1];

console.log(pathname);
```

I am looking at the file locally, and when I put it in the browser `/pathname/myPage.html` my console outputs `/pathname/myPage.html` exactly what I was expecting.

But now, if I change the url to `/pathname/myPage.html?input=yes` the page loads fine, but the console still only logs `/pathname/myPage.html` meanwhile I would like to see `input=yes`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just use [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search)?

Comment: @DavidThomas because I didn't know I could use that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.location.search` returns everything following `?`.

Comment: *Including* the `?`, according to MDN (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search).

Comment: Yes, including `?` just tested. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You could try using just window.location.href

```
var pathname = window.location.href;
console.log(pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(window.location.href);`

Comment: Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers